# Appending strings in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have below code

```
let whereClause =  'CurLocation =' +  GS
                            + ' and Datediff(DD,LastKYCVerified,GetDate()) >= 180 and CreditCard = ' + 'ACTIVE ' +
                            ' and ClientId Not In (Select ClientId from KYCChangeInfo(Nolock))';
```

while executing in the database GS should be with single quotes as CurLocation is a string varable. how to add singlequotes to GS and ACTIVE

Comment: where clause added in the sql query at the DB

Comment: Check any of the tutorials out there on how to work with strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Representing single and double quotation marks in a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468607/representing-single-and-double-quotation-marks-in-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let whereClause =  'CurLocation =\'' +  GS
                            + '\' and Datediff(DD,LastKYCVerified,GetDate()) >= 180 and CreditCard = \'' + 'ACTIVE ' +
                            '\' and ClientId Not In (Select ClientId from KYCChangeInfo(Nolock))';
```